# Google Sheets formulas based on two cells dependent of each other - Appscript maybe?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following issue:

I have Column A and Column B, the user can input data on either A or B and the sheet should do the calculation regardless of what column the data is entered on:

Example: User can enter 1200 in **column A** and **Column B** will display the data /2 (600), but the user can also enter 600 in **column B** and **column A** should display the data * 2 (1200), using formulas will not be an option because if there are formulas in both columns and the user enters the information will delete the formula in either or, is there any alternative on Appscript for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Flow:

- Create a `cfg` object to do what's to be done on each column edit
- On a  simple edit trigger , check which column and sheet is edited  and
- Do calculations as specified by  the `cfg` object

#### Sample script:

```
/**
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Events.SheetsOnEdit} param1
 */
const onEdit = ({ range: rg, value: val }, { columnStart: cs } = rg) => {
  const cfg = {
    1: { offset: 1, calc: num => num / 2 },
    2: { offset: -1, calc: num => num * 2 },
  }[cs];
  /*Only include Sheet1 Column A and B*/
  if (typeof cfg === 'undefined' || rg.getSheet().getName() !== 'Sheet1')
    return;
  rg.offset(0, cfg.offset).setValue(cfg.calc(val));
};
```

#### References:

- [Event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: Works like charm, great use of consts

Comment: How do I change this to be in Columns B and C instead? I tried changing : Offset to 1 and 2 but doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Change 1 and 2 to 2 and 3. Kindly review JavaScript objects in mdn.